# jQuery memoize css for hover effect

Tags: jquery, css, undo, memoization

I want to create a hover effect for an element but want the pre-hover CSS for the element to be the same as before, when hovering out again. So, I don't want to inadvertantly override prior styles when hovering out of the element again. In other words - an easy way to memoize the css state of an element and to restore that state later.

Ideas?

Comment: You cannot just use `:hover` or an additional class that you apply on `hover`?

Comment: m90: They might need to trigger the hover style when an element receives keyboard focus (e.g. for accessibility the user mightn't be using the mouse).

Comment: Sly_cardinal: he could (also) use :focus for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just create a new css class. and on hovering, use `addClass(_thatclass_)` and when hovering out use `removeClass(_thatclass_)`

Comment: I think this is the best suggestion so far. Makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Trigger your hover CSS by applying a specific class to the elements.

Then when your hover is complete remove the hover class.

This lets CSS handle the style overriding and restoration for you.

Comment: Thanks! Answer rewarded to sha404 because he was a minute faster. But thanks to both of you for quick and very useful answers! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Can you do it in pure CSS, using [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3Ahover)? If you can you should, and it restores the old CSS when not hovering automatically.

[See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/5dBEc/1/), all `div`s have a border that gets bigger when you hover, and shrinks back to normal when you stop hovering. I'll put the CSS here, so this answer is self-contained:

```
div {
   border: 2px solid red;
}

div:hover {
  border-width: 10px;
}
```

(Note that you can use hover anywhere within your selectors, not just at the end e.g. `#myID:hover .childClass`)

Comment: No, because I want to create a hover effect on another element when hovering over a given element. But good suggestion given lack of context.